# Save details on my server(txt file) from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form page with some textboxes on it, which looks like this:

```
<tr style="padding:0 0 15px;">
  <td colspan="2"><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo" value="sr" />
    <label>MR.</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo2" value="sra" />
    <label>MRS.</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo2" value="srta" />
    <label>MS.</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo2" value="dr" />
    <label>DR.</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tipo2" value="prof" />
    <label>PROF.</label><br /><br />
  </td>
</tr>
```

All I really need to do is to save the data on my server (not on the client) in a Javascript/jQuery way and save it into a text file which will get updated with a new line everytime a client clicks on the send button.

Does anyone have a function to do it?

Comment: you got to use ajax..

Comment: This is not possible *only with JavaScript*. You have to use some server-side language like PHP, ASP.NET or even Node.js

Comment: Jqury, ajax or anything like will help me, i just need a code exmple to see how to do it

Comment: Even php will work in this case.

Comment: Background reading: http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript/31405-write-values-txt-file-server.html

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this on your server side

```
<?php
    $file = fopen('form.txt','a');
    fwrite($file,serialize($_REQUEST));
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Or you can enable support for PUT requests on your web server to upload files without server-side code.

Comment: Tweaked it to append instead of overwrite but other than that, +1

Comment: i didnt understand how can i do something with that, what is that 'a'?